# How to create a new variable/array using exisiting array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create two variables(not sure whether it can also called as an array) by using existing arrays. Let's day I need two variables such as,

```
$Date =['2022-01-10', '2022-01-11', '2022-01-12', '2022-01-13'];
$Value =[91, 12,15,16];
```

I am planning to get these two values by using a sql query.

```
$query = "select Date,Value from shop order by Date asc;";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $new_array[] = $row;
}

$date_array = array();
$value_array=array();
foreach($new_array as $array)
{       
   $date_array[]=$array['Date'];
   $value_array[]=$array['Value'];
   

}
$date_array_vals=array_values($date_array);
$value_array_vals=array_values($value_array);
```

I have now `$date_array_vals` and `$value_array_vals` as below.

```
Array ( [0] => 2022-01-02 [1] => 2022-01-03 [2] => 2022-01-04 [3] => 2022-01-05 )
Array ( [0] => 20.8 [1] => 201.5 [2] => 25.6 [3] => 205.5 )
```

How I could retrieve `$Date` and `$Value` as above mentioned?

update: Eventually I need to add these two arrays to following code.

```
$chartConfig = "{
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: [//$date should added],
      datasets: [{
        data: [//$value should added],
        backgroundColor: ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', '#e5e4e2'],
      }]
    },
    options: {
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3',
      },
      legend: {
        display: false    
      }
    }
  }";
```

Comment: You don't need the last two assignments. `$date_array` and `$value_array` are already what you want.

Comment: But those assignments are merely redundant, not a problem. Why doesn't this code do what you want?

Comment: You also don't need `$new_array`. Just push onto the result arrays in the `while` loop.

Comment: Just rename `$date_array` to `$Date` and `$value_array` to `$Value` and you'll have the two variables that you said you want.

Comment: Can I get as I mentioned?comma seperated and wrapped with singla commas?

Comment: That's just the way `print_r()` shows arrays and strings. It doesn't show the quotes or commas.

Comment: Trust me, they're in the arrays.

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you check and confirm still we can add this directly there? I have tried but no any output in the graph?

Comment: Create nested associative arrays. Then use `json_encode()` to create the `$chartconfig` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `$chartconfig` using `json_encode()` after creating the array.

```
$query = "select Date,Value from shop order by Date asc;";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result)){
    $Date = $row['Date'];
    $Value = floatval($row['Value']);
}

$chart = [
    "type" => 'bar',
    "data" => [
        "labels" => $Date,
        "datasets" => [[
            "data" => $Value,
            "backgroundColor" => ['#b87333', 'silver', 'gold', '#e5e4e2'],
        ]]
    ],
    "options" => [
        "title" => [
            "display" => true,
            "text" => 'Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3',
        ],
        "legend" => [
            "display" => false    
        ]
    ]
];

$chartConfig = json_encode($chart);
```

Comment: Seems $Date and $Value is not in the fomat what I need. This was not worked

Comment: You may need to convert the values to float, I've added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do this `$date = implode(',',$Date);`
And in html page Do this `var date = "{$date}"`

```
var datearr = date.split(',');
```

for value do the same above with

```
var valuearr = value.split(',').map(Number);
```

Comment: i just noticed you're doing $chartconfig in php file so just added $date in label

Comment: Normally label is as labels: [2022-01-12,2022-01-13 ...], So don't we need include []  as well?